# xcode ERROR ITMS-90093= this bundle is invalid. apps that include arm64 architecture cannot have minimum OS Version

Tags: ios, xcode, publish

When trying to publish the application I get this error.

[image]

Why Is That? help!

XCode version 6.1.1
base SDK 7.1
deployment target 4.3

Comment: Have you read the message? It's pretty clear

Comment: You are using Xcode 6.1. Why isn't your Base SDK set to iOS 8.1 (Latest) and why do you feel the need to support iOS 4.3? There's virtually no point in supporting anything before iOS 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) Apple referenced:

> Xcode 5.0.1 can build your app with both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries
>   included. This combined binary requires a minimum deployment target of
>   iOS 5.1.1 or later."

Assume that applies to the current Xcode version.

Comment: You are very right. Thanks for the help. Problem solved.  I set deployment target 6.0 and problem solved.